Data Type Conversion : string to numeric while importing dataset (csv) into MapBox Studio
I've been importing csv datasets into mapbox studio. However the numeric fields are automatically imported as string into MapBox Studio dataset , which subsequently makes it impossible to perform "data driven styling" in MapBox Studio.
Any help will be appreciated
All CSV numeric fields are read-into MapBox Studio as "String"

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/csv

Data imported via CSV will be encoded as a string type in the Mapbox Studio dataset editor. If you want to code any of your imported data as numbers, you can edit the fields individually in the dataset editor or upload your data in GeoJSON format.

